# angular-ui typeahead custom template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I want to customize the typeahead dropdown to show "name" and "original".
The json source is in the form

```
[
...
   {
    "_id": "56d0524c07e5a2940eb059c6",
    "name": "english name",
    "original": "original name",
    "__v": 0
   },
...
]
```

As I saw in docs, I tried this custom template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="custom.html">
<a>
    <span ng-bind-html="match.label.name | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
    <small ng-bind-html="match.label.original | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></small>
</a>
```

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.model.referringCourt" typeahead-template-url="custom.html" uib-typeahead="item.name as item for item in search($viewValue)">
```

It doesn't work. The current result I get is on selection I see a single string in model, not the whole object selected.
What's the proper way to:

- use a custom template with 2 (or 3) values
- define which one have to be shown in input field
- keep the whole object as model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks I solved by myself, actually the example "Custom templates for results" is pretty much what I was looking for. The solution is filter the source like that

```
 uib-typeahead="item as item.name for item in search($viewValue) | filter:{name:$viewValue}"
```

Answer (score 0):

alfredopacino,

use match.model :)

match.label is only display value of your model item.

see line 43 in

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview